# Calcite create schema with sql

Tags: apache-calcite

Is there a way to create a schema for calcite using existing sql for table creation?

Here is my code, for example:

`FrameworkConfig config = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder().defaultSchema(defaultSchema).build();`

`Planner planner = Frameworks.getPlanner(config);`

`SqlNode parse = planner.parse(sql);`

`SqlNode validate = planner.validate(parse);`

I need to provide a defaultSchema for the `config`, otherwise the validate will fail.

But I only got a string contains `CREATE TABLE A (a int not null);`.

How can I generate such a defaultSchema using the sql string like `CREATE TABLE A (a int not null);`.

I searched for the SchemaFactory of the Calcite but got nothing.

Is there any way to create such a schema?